# How can I read the HTTP request body in android?

Tags: android, httprequest

How can I read the `http` post request body in android?
I have used the `webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(), webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()` to read the body of `http` request, But it gives no result. Do we have any other alternative to this?

Comment: what you want to suppose to do?

Answer (score 0):

you want to know the url?

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        //do something with url
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, i want to see the request body.